# Shelling out in Ruby

Tags: ruby, bash

I am trying to run shell scripts instead of dealing with Ruby code to match some regular expressions from the result of a `git log --stat` command. I my shell I can run the following:

```
$ if [[ ' 1 file changed, 2 insertions(+), 3 deletions(-)' =~ ([0-9]*).insertion ]]; then echo ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}; fi
2
```

But, when I am trying it in Ruby (irb) with backticks:

```
2.2.0 :001 > `if [[ ' 1 file changed, 2 insertions(+), 3 deletions(-)' =~ ([0-9]*).insertion ]]; then echo ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}; fi`
sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected (expecting "then")
 => ""
```

To simplify the problem I've tried in the shell the following:

```
$ if [[ 'example' =~ am ]]; then echo 'match'; fi;
match
```

But again, when trying it in Ruby:

```
2.2.0 :001 > `if [[ 'example' =~ am ]]; then echo 'match'; fi;`
sh: 1: [[: not found
 => ""
```

How do I deal with specific characters like `(` and `[`?

Comment: Why wouldn't you simply do this in ruby?  You're making this much more difficult... ??

Comment: Isn't `[[` a bash-ism that the standard shell won't understand?

Comment: I am doing it in this way because it is faster, I need to analyse huge repositories.

Comment: I am using gnu bash 4.3.11. I'm not used to write shell scripts, so `[[`could be a bash-ism, but doesn't ruby call the default OS shell? I've also try with `%x[ ]`syntax with the same results.

Comment: ruby calls bin/sh. This could be just a symlink to /bin/bash or it could be something else (eg dash on Ubuntu or Debian)

Answer (score 0):

It may be worth seeing what the ruby git gem can do, but here's a ruby solution to read the output without having to deal with shell regexp.

```
IO.popen('git log --stat') do |io|
  while line = io.gets
    if line =~ /(\d+) files changed, (\d+) insertions..., (\d+) deletions/
      files_changed = $1.to_i
      insertions = $2.to_i
      deletions = $3.to_i

      # Do something real here
    end
  end
end
```